# How to specify that "all dates" are included in a mentioned period of time?

Tags: word-request, dates

When I'd like to specify dates to do some task, how can I express that the last date should be included in the provided period?

For example:

> From 5th to 7th March

Meaning March 5th, March 6th *and* March 7th.

Answer (score 1):

The least ambiguous would be to use "up to and including":

> From the 5th up to and including the 7th of March

Using *through* works as well:

> From the 5th through the 7th of March

since that word means

> 4 c : to and including
>   // Monday *through* Friday

<sub>(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through))</sub>

Comment: A variation on "up to and including" is the single word **inclusive**: "from the 5th to the 7th of March, inclusive."